# Hide one div on hover of another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a sidebar navigation. I want the circles (.circle-indicator) to disappear when the sidebar (.nav-sidebar) expands on hover. Can this be done with CSS or do I need to use javascript? How would I do this?

Here's the code for the page

```css
body {
    margin:-20px;
}

.nav-sidebar {
    position:fixed;
    width:10px;
    background-color:#000;
    color:#fff;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 100px 20px 0 20px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}    

.nav-sidebar:hover {
    width:300px;
    transition-duration:1s;

}

.nav-sidebar a {
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.nav-sidebar ul {
    list-style:none;
}

.nav-sidebar sidebar-links li {
    padding-bottom:1em;
}

.nav-sidebar .circle-indicator {
    position:fixed;
    left:-33px;
    top:40vh;
}

.nav-sidebar .circle-indicator ul li {
    margin-bottom:1em;
    display:block;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    padding:0;
}

.nav-sidebar .circle-indicator ul li a:active {
    background-color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>    
</head>
    
<body>
    <div class="nav-sidebar">
        <div class="circle-indicator">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Item 1"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Item 2"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Item 3"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Item 4"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Item 5"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div> <!-- end circle-indicator -->
        <div class="sidebar-links">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Item 1">Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Item 2">Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Item 3">Item 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Item 4">Item 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Item 5">Item 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div> <!-- end sidebar-links -->
    </div> <!-- end nav-sidebar -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can try it with opacity, like some answers say, but move the `transition-duration` to the simple `.nav-sidebar` to make it nice and smooth on mouse exit.

Comment: Could you let me know what is not working with the answer a gave, so I will be able to adjust and you to accept?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
.nav-sidebar:hover .circle-indicator{
    display:none;
}
```

```css
body {
    margin:-20px;
}

.nav-sidebar {
    position:fixed;
    width:10px;
    background-color:#000;
    color:#fff;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 100px 20px 0 20px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}    

.nav-sidebar:hover {
    width:300px;
    transition-duration:1s;

}

.nav-sidebar a {
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.nav-sidebar ul {
    list-style:none;
}

.nav-sidebar sidebar-links li {
    padding-bottom:1em;
}

.nav-sidebar .circle-indicator {
    position:fixed;
    left:-33px;
    top:40vh;
}

.nav-sidebar .circle-indicator ul li {
    margin-bottom:1em;
    display:block;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    padding:0;
}

.nav-sidebar .circle-indicator ul li a:active {
    background-color:#fff;
}

.nav-sidebar:hover .circle-indicator{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>    
</head>
    
<body>
    <div class="nav-sidebar">
        <div class="circle-indicator">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Item 1"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Item 2"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Item 3"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Item 4"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Item 5"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div> <!-- end circle-indicator -->
        <div class="sidebar-links">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Item 1">Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Item 2">Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Item 3">Item 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Item 4">Item 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Item 5">Item 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div> <!-- end sidebar-links -->
    </div> <!-- end nav-sidebar -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This rule will do that

```
.nav-sidebar:hover .circle-indicator {
    display: none;
}
```

Or with a transition

```
.nav-sidebar:hover .circle-indicator {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
```

Sample snippet

```css
body {
    margin:-20px;
}

.nav-sidebar {
    position:fixed;
    width:10px;
    background-color:#000;
    color:#fff;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 100px 20px 0 20px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}    

.nav-sidebar:hover {
    width:300px;
    transition-duration:1s;

}
.nav-sidebar:hover .circle-indicator {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.nav-sidebar a {
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.nav-sidebar ul {
    list-style:none;
}

.nav-sidebar sidebar-links li {
    padding-bottom:1em;
}

.nav-sidebar .circle-indicator {
    position:fixed;
    left:-33px;
    top:40vh;
}

.nav-sidebar .circle-indicator ul li {
    margin-bottom:1em;
    display:block;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    padding:0;
}

.nav-sidebar .circle-indicator ul li a:active {
    background-color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>    
</head>
    
<body>
    <div class="nav-sidebar">
        <div class="circle-indicator">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Item 1"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Item 2"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Item 3"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Item 4"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Item 5"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div> <!-- end circle-indicator -->
        <div class="sidebar-links">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Item 1">Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Item 2">Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Item 3">Item 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Item 4">Item 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Item 5">Item 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div> <!-- end sidebar-links -->
    </div> <!-- end nav-sidebar -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Good answers by LGSon and Brad, but I'd do it with `opacity` and a `transition`. You cannot transition `dispay: none`

```css
body {
    margin:-20px;
}

.nav-sidebar {
    position:fixed;
    width:10px;
    background-color:#000;
    color:#fff;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 100px 20px 0 20px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}    

.nav-sidebar:hover {
    width:300px;
    transition-duration:1s;

}

.nav-sidebar a {
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.nav-sidebar ul {
    list-style:none;
}

.nav-sidebar sidebar-links li {
    padding-bottom:1em;
}

.nav-sidebar .circle-indicator {
    position:fixed;
    left:-33px;
    top:40vh;
 transition: opacity 1s;
}

.nav-sidebar .circle-indicator ul li {
    margin-bottom:1em;
    display:block;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    padding:0;
}

.nav-sidebar .circle-indicator ul li a:active {
    background-color:#fff;
}

.nav-sidebar:hover .circle-indicator {
 opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>    
</head>
    
<body>
    <div class="nav-sidebar">
        <div class="circle-indicator">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Item 1"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Item 2"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Item 3"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Item 4"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Item 5"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div> <!-- end circle-indicator -->
        <div class="sidebar-links">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Item 1">Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Item 2">Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Item 3">Item 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Item 4">Item 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Item 5">Item 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div> <!-- end sidebar-links -->
    </div> <!-- end nav-sidebar -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, LGSon. Didn't see that

Answer (score 0):

You can create this effect with the following styles

```
<style>
  .nav-sidebar:hover .circle-indicator {
    display:none;
  }
</style>
```

```css
body {
    margin:-20px;
}

.nav-sidebar {
    position:fixed;
    width:10px;
    background-color:#000;
    color:#fff;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 100px 20px 0 20px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}    

.nav-sidebar:hover {
    width:300px;
    transition-duration:1s;

}

.nav-sidebar a {
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.nav-sidebar ul {
    list-style:none;
}

.nav-sidebar sidebar-links li {
    padding-bottom:1em;
}

.nav-sidebar .circle-indicator {
    position:fixed;
    left:-33px;
    top:40vh;
}

.nav-sidebar .circle-indicator ul li {
    margin-bottom:1em;
    display:block;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    padding:0;
}

.nav-sidebar .circle-indicator ul li a:active {
    background-color:#fff;
}

.nav-sidebar:hover .circle-indicator {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>    
</head>
    
<body>
    <div class="nav-sidebar">
        <div class="circle-indicator">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Item 1"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Item 2"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Item 3"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Item 4"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Item 5"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div> <!-- end circle-indicator -->
        <div class="sidebar-links">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Item 1">Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Item 2">Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Item 3">Item 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Item 4">Item 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" alt="Item 5">Item 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div> <!-- end sidebar-links -->
    </div> <!-- end nav-sidebar -->
</body>
</html>
```